# Why does %AppData% in windows 7 seemingly points to wrong folder?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

The best way to find and get to AppData folder (specifically windows 7) is to type `%AppData%` in start command. But it takes me to `C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming`

Why does it takes me to `Roaming` folder when the actual AppData Folder is one level up? It happens on both computers I have.

Comment: removed it, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3):

There is no environment variable for the root "AppData" folder because no one should ever put data there. Instead, applications put data into subfolders of the "AppData" folder depending on the nature of that data.

There are three subfolders:

- Roaming
- Local
- LocalLow

The regular old `%AppData%` environment variable points to the path for the "Roaming" subfolder, which is where most applications should store their data, unless they have a specific reason that that data should *not* roam with the user's profile.

If you want the "Local" (non-roaming) sub-folder, use the `%LocalAppData%` environment variable instead.

As for typing this into the Start → Run dialog, that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Data that is stored here is *not* intended for user consumption. It is private data stored by applications for their own use—things like configuration files, databases, etc. User-facing data should be in the Documents folder or at a path specified by the user. If you're a software developer accessing this folder for testing purposes, just go up one level.

Comment: Right I only wanted to get in there to see memory dump files which are indeed in %LocalAppData%. And thanks this make sense but still it would have been better if they name it %RoamingAppData% since that's where it actually points.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `appdata` (not `%appdata%`) in *Run* dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) takes you to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData` (i.e. `%AppData%\..`).